# Setup VPN on Linux, connect through ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn, openvpn

I want to securely connect to linux through ssh. I heard that to setup a VPN is more secure.
But I don't know how to setup **VPN-connect-only** in Linux.
I want to restrict directly connection except through VPN.

Answer (score 4):

VPN stands for Virtual Private Network. SSH stands for Secure Shell.

VPN simply provides a more secure (and perhaps more convenient) means of accessing your servers across insecure or public networks using other protocols.

Think of it this way.

The VPN is like a Turducken. The SSH protocol is still necessary to actually get to your server, and is like the birds on the inside. Most people can't SEE inside the turkey to know what is in there, but you know what it is and have the keys (knife) to open up the VPN packets (outer turkey layer) so that you can get at the inner bird.

In short, You cannot connect to your server ONLY through VPN without using some other protocol to handle logins, such as SSH. They are not mutually-exclusive.

Comment: ... I have no idea what a Turducken is

Comment: Courtesy of Wikipedia: A turducken is a dish consisting of a de-boned chicken stuffed into a de-boned duck, which itself is stuffed into a de-boned turkey. The word turducken is a portmanteau of turkey, duck, and chicken or hen.

Comment: I want to know how to configure VPN-connect-only in linux.

Comment: That's a rather vague request. I'd suggest editing your answer and providing a more verbose request as to exactly what you mean by that statement. A 'VPN-only-request' COULD mean that you want to connect using the VPN protocol which is impossible because it doesn't do that OR that you wish to restrict access to the remote machine to only those machines on the VPN. You need to update your question before you can reasonably expect further assistance.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know ssh is undoubtedly secured. However if you want to configure VPN on Debian Linux, You can follow [this link.](http://www.howtogeek.com/51237/setting-up-a-vpn-pptp-server-on-debian/)

Comment: I want to know how to configure VPN-connect-only in linux.

Comment: What do you mean with VPN-connect-only?